# How to fix this screen tearing in Vim

Tags: vim, xorg, xterm

[image: screen tearing example]

I've been seeing this kind of screen tearing with Vim and some other programs. It's intermittent and I'm pretty sure it only happens when a program puts `\r` on it's stdout, I'm not sure if there's a term for that. I'm using `xterm` with these [`Xresources`](https://github.com/danhab99/dotfiles/blob/master/.Xresources). Can anyone reccomend a solution?

Screenfetch:

```
 dan@workstation
 OS: Manjaro 21.1.0 Pahvo
 Kernel: x86_64 Linux 5.10.56-1-MANJARO
 Uptime: 27m
 Packages: 1684
 Shell: zsh 5.8
 Resolution: 5760x1080
 DE: GNOME
 WM: i3
 GTK Theme: Adwaita [GTK2/3]
 Icon Theme: Adwaita
 Font: Cantarell 11
 Disk: 332G / 955G (37%)
 CPU: Intel Core i9-10850K @ 20x 5.2GHz [57.0°C]
 GPU: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2060
 RAM: 4093MiB / 32003MiB
```

Comment: What does `echo $TERM` show?  Are you using a terminal multiplexer like screen or tmux?

Comment: @bk2204 `xterm-256color`. I should note that I'm not experiencing this issue at the moment as I had to reinstall Manjaro for unrelated reasons... IDK if we should keep this open for other people who might have this problem.